# Do apple native media player play Play-ready media files

Tags: iphone

I have been researching on whether we can create an app which will play Play-ready protected DRM video files in apple's native media player. But what I could collect is that apple will not allow DRM protected video files to be streamed or played through media player. However if this the case, how there exists solutions which can decrypt the files and play them from within the app?
Also as per my R&D, the device should support play-ready file format. Hence now OEM's are launching phones like HTC, nokia with play-ready support. But how will we provide support on apple devices?
Please, any inputs or thoughts on this will surely be helpful.

Comment: Is my question an invalid question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested by the solutions of 
Discretix: http://www.discretix.com/DRM/index.html
and
and Authentec: http://authentec.com/a/downloadabledrm.aspx?gclid=CNT399qy4a4CFUG_3godhRa2YA

Answer (score 0):

Creating an app that uses PlayReady should be possible but to enable ReadyPlay via the "native media player" is up to Apple alone - they control the installed codecs. Getting [PlayReady](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayReady) on an apple product may be tricky. As a Microsoft propriety DRM format you will need to get [licensing from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/PlayReady/Licensing/request.mspx) and pass the appstore at Apple. Any tools offered for PlayReady will be PC centric, the DRM may be platform agnostic but without IOs friendly tools you have a lot of work ahead.